# open source logs analyzing and collector

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, logs, webserver

I have a lot of Linux servers which working as web servers I am searching for an opensource software for log analyzing and collecting all server logs such as web access, web errors for each site also logging in logs, any ideas or experiences?

Answer (score 1):

A few too look at here:

Graylog:
https://www.graylog.org/

Logwatch:
https://linode.com/docs/uptime/monitoring/monitor-systems-logwatch/

Splunk:
https://www.splunk.com/

Logstash:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html

Logwatch is simple and easy to configure for alerting purposes. If you want a fancy GUI any of the rest are for you.

Answer (score 1):

For monitoring logs of many Linux servers, the best strategy is sending the logs to a central syslog server.

Depending on what large means to you, you can send them via pointing rsyslog/syslog-ng to one big syslog server, and/or using a log shipper such as [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) or [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash).

On top of that, you can think of using the [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack) and [Graphana](https://grafana.com).

I would also thinking of monitoring the infra-structure/servers either for availability, [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org)/[Sensu](https://sensuapp.org), and in collecting SNMP stats of their performance ([Cacti](https://www.cacti.net) or [Observium](http://www.observium.org) are easy to use).

At the end of the day, many of the tools you can select, including the @Declan suggestions, depends on your know-how and the size of your infra-structure.